# Save images from Form to database using ImageField Django

Tags: python, django, image, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save images from my Form to my database in django. All of my other CharFields seem to save from my form but not the images. When I go to admin I can upload and save images to a specified media folder and it works however, the images dont seem to save. Please help very confused, also new to this so my code may be a mess, much help is needed. Thanks. Links to my code below:

```
[updated models][1]
[updated settings][2]
[updated urls][3]
[updated views.py][1]
```

links to code:
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td7Mv.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31vNB.png
      [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXhg7.png
      [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu5BC.png

Comment: You should add relevant parts of your code in question only (instead of images of source code). Makes question more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In your models.py file you need to change all your ImageField to this

```
media_gallery = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

> This saves the location of the image in the database

Later you can access the image in templates like this

```
src = "{{ model_name.media_gallery.url }}"
```

After everything lastly add this code to your settings.py file

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Please update your main project's urls.py file by adding this code at the end

```
urlpatterns = [] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hey Zohaib, I made the changes you suggested however, when I fill out the form none of the images save and my media folder remains empty unless I upload the media from the admin page. Do you think this could be the way my views.py is saving the images? Do i need to retrieve images differently than: form.cleaned_data["media_gallery"]. Some pages seem to recommend a request.FILES but I am not understanding it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you show me the snapshot of of models.py & settings.py where you made the changes and also the log

Comment: Hey Zohaib, Thank you for getting back to me! I took snapshots and updated my initial post with the new snapshots of models, settings and urls.

Comment: Look at my answer, I have updated the answer and now your code should work as expected, just follow the guidelines in the answer, and get back to me if it works

Comment: Hey Zohaib, I ended up having to update my views to include request.FILES to save the images properly. Ill update my original post with the corrected views

Comment: @kmacri If the solution answer was good for your satisfaction, you should upvote the answer